# Python 2.7 - unpacking iterable object throws syntax error

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am learning python and I have as simple list as this

```
z = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

and I am just trying to unpack it, which throws me syntax error.

```
a,*b,c = z
>>> a,*b,c = z
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a,*b,c = z
      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried changing the order of variable as well but same error. Any suggestion pls.

Comment: `*b` is not a valid name for a variable

Comment: What were you try to get with `*b`? Were you trying to separate the first and last element from the middle of the list?

Comment: Extended unpacking is only implemented/possible in python 3 - your question is tagged as python 2.7 and 3.x. What version are you using?

Comment: Ref https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/ and https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.0.html#new-syntax

Comment: @TomDalton I am using 2.7 as mentioned in title of question but I guessed that it might be due to version so I want to reach out wider audience for their suggestion

Answer (score 3):

Here is a quote from [PEP-3132](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/#id6)

> For example, if seq is a slicable sequence, all the following
>   assignments are equivalent if seq has at least three elements:
>
> ```
> a, b, c = seq[0], list(seq[1:-1]), seq[-1]
> a, *b, c = seq
> [a, *b, c] = seq
> ```

In Python2.7, only the first version is legal syntax.

Since you already know `z` is a list, you can just write

```
a, b, c = z[0], z[1:-1], z[-1]
```

This will work for Python2.7 and Python3.x

Comment: If `seq` is a generator this won't work, better to do `lst = list(seq)` then slice `lst`.

Comment: A generator is neither slicable nor a sequence.

Answer (score 3):

What your are trying to do does not work in Python2 because it does not have support for extended tuple unpacking - you pretty much have to use slicing.

```
>>> z = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> a, b, c = z[0], z[1:-1], z[-1]
>>> a
1
>>> b
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> c
9
```

Using Python3, you are allowed [one wildcard](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

Demo:

```
>>> z = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
>>> a, *b, c = z
>>> a
1
>>> b
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
>>> c
9
>>> *a, b, c = z
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> b
8
>>> c
9
>>> *a, *b, c = z
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: two starred expressions in assignment
```

Python3.5 comes with some [additional unpacking generalizations](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.5.html#whatsnew-pep-448)

```
>>> [1, 2, *[3, 4]]
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

Comment: And it's a damn shame that the new generalizations don't work in comprehensions, or we could write `[*sublist for sublist in nested_list]` in 3.5 to flatten a list of lists.

Comment: Eh. Works with generator expressions, so: `[*itertools.chain(*nested_list)]` works. Not too bad; shortens if you import `chain` into global namespace directly.